# Sonar Runner execution error on IssueListener?

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a job that I run on a monthly basis at this time. Lately, I'm encounting an Issue that I don't get when running sonar-runner (version 2.5.1):

> INFO: Scanner configuration file:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_2.5.1/conf/sonar-runner.properties
>   INFO: Project configuration file:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tpk-extra-package/tpx-extra-tools/tpk-extra-tools_build/sonar-project.properties
>   INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.5.1 INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation
>   (64-bit) INFO: Linux 4.4.0-98-generic amd64 INFO: Error stacktraces
>   are turned on. INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/IssueListener at
>   org.sonar.runner.batch.DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch(DefaultBatchFactory.java:44)
>   at
>   org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.start(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:56)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source) at
>   org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doStart(EmbeddedRunner.java:251)
>   at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:187)
>   at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:182)
>   at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:76) at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.IssueListener at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

The host where I run this command did not change over the last month (since the last successful run): same kernel, same java 1.8 version, ...

I've checked using strace/ltrace but couldn't find what is the issue.
I try to run the same sonar-runner on a different system (another linux distro with different kernel and java - but yet 1.8), still the same stacktrace.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Something has definitely changed, otherwise you wouldn't get the problem. Have you updated any of your code, libraries or deployment files?

Comment: Yes but no
Yes we updated our code but this error spawns before the code is being even tested.

I agree something changed but I wasn't able to find out what/when/where

Comment: I did some digging, and it looks like you might want to update your version of `sonar-runner`. Or possilby search whether something in there was updated in the meantime.

Comment: Not a default in Jenkins (as the one I use is the last official via the UI) but will test the last compatible one (2.6.1).

Comment: forcing installation of the 2.6.1 solved the case (thanks)
Now I need to understand why this version is not present in the dropdown menu in Jenkins

Comment: Maybe this will help: "You may force this refresh by clicking 'Check Now' button in Manage Plugins > Advanced tab" (see [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins))

Comment: The plugin itself is up2date
The issue is with the dropdown menu when configuring the tool itself